# Flutter : A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeNativeLibsTask$MergeNativeLibsTaskWorkAction

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDevelopmentDebugNativeLibs'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeNativeLibsTask$MergeNativeLibsTaskWorkAction
> 2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so' from inputs:
> - C:\Users\User.gradle\caches\transforms-3\e46e17d597ff8468963db24ef7ea08f6\transformed\jetified-arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-74d16627b940bb15e50891f82cad6c3e3465bd6d\arm64-v8a\libc++_shared.so
> - C:\Users\User.gradle\caches\transforms-3\98560fdb2c1a483439c351cd6deea1fc\transformed\jetified-pdfium-android-1.9.2\jni\arm64-v8a\libc++_shared.so
> If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see
> https://developer.android.com/r/tools/jniLibs-vs-imported-targets

so this error that preventing me to run my application happen after i upgrade my flutter and all of my dependencies

after that i do this:

```
packagingOptions {
    resources.excludes.add("META-INF/*")
    // exclude '/lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'

}
```

Comment: How are you excluding `/lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so`? also, your question doesn't provide any context or insight on what your issue is.

Comment: Do you depend on any pdf viewer packages in your code? I did some research and it seems `flutter_pdfviewer` and `pdfx` are both broken with flutter `3.16.0`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeNativeLibsTask$MergeNativeLibsTaskWorkAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74325460/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-com-android-build-gradle-internal-tasks-merge)

Comment: thank you very much. already wrote what i do to solve my problem for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jose Georges says, it's all good when I downgrade my Flutter to version 3.13.9. The issue is with flutter_pdfviewer 1.3.2 and flutter 3.16.0.

Answer (score 2):

This issue indeed comes from all the Flutter packages with a PDF viewer on Flutter 3.16.0 and it seems to happen only on Android.

So, the temporary solution is to add this in your app gradle inside `android{}`:

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
}
```